# undefined variable passing a not check

Tags: php, ajax

I'm not really certain where the problem lies but I am passing a variable through ajax and it is not being caught if I pass a blank when I check it with !$varname

Here is my ajax function:

```
var subscribe = function(){
  var dataString = $("#subinput").val();
   $.ajax ({
   url: '<?php echo $path ?>',
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'email=' + dataString.value,
   datatype: 'JSON',
   success: function(results){
     if(results.err == '1'){
        $('.onconfirmation').css('color','#f00');
     }else{
        $('.onconfirmation').css('color','#5A5A5A');
     }

     $('.onconfirmation').innerHTML(results.message);
     $('.onconfirmation').fadeIn();
     //alert(results);
   }
 });
```

and here is my PHP:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(!$email){
    $o['err'] = '1';
    $o['message'] = 'Please do not leave this field blank';
}/*elseif(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $o['err'] = '1';
    $o['message'] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}else{
    $o['err'] = '0';
    $o['message'] = 'Thank you for your subscription';
}*/

ob_start();
var_dump($o);
$out = ob_get_clean();

mail('[REDACTED]','debug',$out);
//$o = json_encode($o);
//return ($o);
?>
```

As you can see it's in a debugging state at the moment, but if I pass a blank value through into this, the email I am getting is `NULL`. If I email myself the `$email` variable instead of the `$out` variable, the email I get is `undefined`, but if I remove the `!` from the if statement, the email I get is:

```
array(2) {
  ["err"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["message"]=>
  string(36) "Please do not leave this field blank"
}
```

I'm sure I am just missing something awfully simple, I always am, but I honestly can't figure this one out. Any help would be massively appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var subscribe = function(){
  var dataString = $("#subinput").val();
   $.ajax ({
   url: '<?php echo $path ?>',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { email : dataString },
   datatype: 'JSON',
   success: function(results){
     if(results.err == '1'){
        $('.onconfirmation').css('color','#f00');
     }else{
        $('.onconfirmation').css('color','#5A5A5A');
     }

     $('.onconfirmation').innerHTML(results.message);
     $('.onconfirmation').fadeIn();
     //alert(results);
   }
 });
```

see the line

> data: { email : dataString }

Once you have the val() you shouldn't use " .value " and when POST-ing data this way is the correct way to add keys and values.

At PHP do those things..

```
<?php
$o = array();

if(!isset($_POST['email']) OR empty($_POST['email'])){
    $o['err'] = '1';
    $o['message'] = 'Please do not leave this field blank';
    echo json_encode($o);
    exit();
}

$email = $_POST['email']; 

.......other code
```

The exit() stops PHP from reading the next lines at your file so IF emial is not set or empty it wont do any further tasks.

Comment: Cheers. As I said in the answer above, I knew it would be some stupid bit of code I had left in, I just couldn't see it. Thanks for the cleaner PHP suggestion too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
var subscribe = function(){
  var dataString = $("#subinput").val();
   $.ajax ({
   url: '<?php echo $path ?>',
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'email=' + dataString.value,
   datatype: 'JSON',
   success: function(results){
     if(results.err == '1'){
        $('.onconfirmation').css('color','#f00');
     }else{
        $('.onconfirmation').css('color','#5A5A5A');
     }

     $('.onconfirmation').innerHTML(results.message);
     $('.onconfirmation').fadeIn();
     //alert(results);
   }
 });
```

with this:

```
var subscribe = function(){
  var dataString = $("#subinput").val();
   $.ajax ({
   url: '<?php echo $path ?>',
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'email=' + dataString,
   datatype: 'JSON',
   success: function(results){
     if(results.err == '1'){
        $('.onconfirmation').css('color','#f00');
     }else{
        $('.onconfirmation').css('color','#5A5A5A');
     }

     $('.onconfirmation').innerHTML(results.message);
     $('.onconfirmation').fadeIn();
     //alert(results);
   }
 });
```

val() actually returns the value of an element.

Comment: I knew it would be some stupid user error of mine I just couldn't see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataString = $("#subinput").val();
// ...
data: 'email=' + dataString.value,
```

You used [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of #subinput, which is a string. Then, you attempted to read a "value" property of that string, which does not exist. When you concatenate the undefined value with "email=", JavaScript converts it to the string "undefined".

To fix this, you can just change `dataString.value` to `dataString`. However, for the sake of those who use the `+` symbol in their e-mail addresses ([especially Gmail users](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200908/plus_signs_in_email_addresses.html)), which your PHP code would interpret as a space, you probably should change the entire line to:

```
data: {email: dataString},
```

Passing a JavaScript object with the name-value pairs to jQuery allows it to properly query string escape the `+`.